# Parse JavaScript variable declarations

Tags: javascript, php

Is here any way to parse JavaScript syntax in PHP?

I want to get all JS variables in PHP array

```
$string = 'var variable = "hello";
           var thisIsVariableToo = "world";
           var and = ["this", "is"];
           var its = new Array("amazing");
           var nice = null;';
```

I want to get in PHP from that (^^^) string:

```
$string = [
    "variable" => "hello",
    "thisIsVariableToo" => "world",
    "and" => ["this", "is"],
    "its" => ["amazing"],
    "nice" => null
]
```

How I can do that?

Comment: You'll have to use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to pass the data to PHP.

Comment: @BrianRay: I think you misunderstood the question.  An HTTP layer doesn't appear to be involved here at all.  The OP has a string which contains JavaScript code, and wants to parse the syntax of that string into a structure.

Comment: what is your goal? javascript is client-side, php server-side: there are not interaction. You want extract javascript variables from html code?

Comment: @fusion3k My goal: get all js variables from javascript string and parse it to php array

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699398/best-way-to-parse-a-javascript-file-in-php-to-extract-the-array-defined-inside-i)

Comment: @fusion3k this parses ONLY THE CONTENT OF THE arrays. Please read my question again.

Comment: @David OP updated the question indicating that a POST _is_ involved.

Comment: you can add `elseif( strpos($line, 'var variable'))` etc... Also you can try [this parser](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/jparser/index.html)

Comment: Please show your POST content.

Comment: @DaveChen I send the JavaScript string by POST and the JavaScript does NOT EXCUTE in the page.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak: Why exactly are you sending JavaScript *language* to the server to be parsed?  What are you intending to accomplish here?

Comment: @fusion3k the POST content is that JavaScript in the question

Comment: @PatrickQ: For small values of "involved".  Regardless of where the string came from, so far the question hasn't *really* changed.  The OP is trying to parse the language into a structure.  "Use AJAX" doesn't exactly address that :-/

Comment: @David I want to make a deobfuscator, that replaces `var test = ["hi", "hello"]; alert(test[1])` to `alert("hello")`

Comment: @SzymonMarczak Been made by Google already. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/2t5VOZl.png) and [Link](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Avar%2520test%2520%253D%2520%255B%2522hi%2522%252C%2520%2522hello%2522%255D%253B%2520alert(test%255B1%255D)%253B%250A). Click advanced and then click Compile.

Comment: @DaveChen but it doesn't work well. Try this: goo.gl/l2Q9Jx

Comment: This question has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
$str = 'var variable = "hello";
var thisIsVariableToo = "world";
var and = ["this", "is"];
var its = new Array("amazing");
var nice = null;';

preg_match_all('~^var\s+([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*;?\s*$~imu', $str, $matchesAll, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$arr = array();
foreach ($matchesAll as $matches) {
    $arr[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Which outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [variable] => "hello"
    [thisIsVariableToo] => "world"
    [and] => ["this", "is"]
    [its] => new Array("amazing")
    [nice] => null
)
```

Comment: This is really nice! Thank You! Please remember that the `var` may not be used to set the variable... Anyway, good job!

Comment: I did a mistake. It works very well! Thanks!